# How to change numbers in variables defined with a loop?

Tags: expression-manipulation, procedural-programming

I am trying to change the number which is part of the variable name with a loop.

What I want to changue is the following:

```
r1i = fuv1[w1] + fuv1'[w1] (c - w1);
r1f = fuv1[w0] + fuv1'[2500] (c - w0);
wop1 = Solve[r1i == r1f, c][[1, 1, 2]];
```

where `fuvi` is a function previously defined.

I would like to make a loop that replaces the integer 1 appearing in the various identifiers with another integer. The final result should be list of compound expressions that read as follows:

```
r1i = fuv1[w1] + fuv1'[w1] (c - w1);
r1f = fuv1[w0] + fuv1'[2500] (c - w0);
wop1 = Solve[r1i == r1f, c][[1, 1, 2]];

r2i = fuv2[w2] + fuv2'[w2] (c - w2);
r2f = fuv2[w0] + fuv2'[2500] (c - w0);
wop2 = Solve[r2i == r2f, c][[1, 1, 2]];

r3i = fuv3[w3] + fuv3'[w3] (c - w3);
r3f = fuv3[w0] + fuv3'[2500] (c - w0);
wop3 = Solve[r3i == r3f, c][[1, 1, 2]];

...
```

Comment: I'd suggest packaging those three lines in a function, which you can then `Map[]` over a list. Something like `pamela[w_] := Module[{r1i, r1f, c}, (* stuff *)]`.

Comment: @J.M.'sennui. I think the OP wants to be able to promgramatically transform the three line compound expression into a sequence of edited compound expressions of arbitrary length and then execute them all.

Comment: You can use subdcripted variables, e.g. `fuv[1]` (used as `fuv[1][w1](c-w1)`). If you absolutely must use "simple" variables, see `Symbol`.

Comment: If you really want the list you mention, you would have to enclose the statements with `Hold` . Otherwise the expressions will be executed at once. It is not clear to me if you want the list or the side effects of the list.

Answer (score 2):

If you want the side effects of the list, not the list itself:

```
Clear["Globals`*"]
fun[n_] :=
  ToExpression[
   ToString[
    StringForm[
     "r`1`i=fuv`1`[w`1`]+fuv`1`'[w`1`] \
(c-w`1`);r`1`f=fuv`1`[w0]+fuv`1`'[2500] (c-w0);wop`1`=Solve[r`1`i\
\[Equal]r`1`f,c][[1,1,2]];", n]]];
fun[1]; {r1i, r1f, wop1}
fun[2]; {r2i, r2f, wop2}
fun[3]; {r3i, r3f, wop3}
```

[image]